# Cannot convert call result type "Bool" to expected type int?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm trying to change daysMonth[2] to 29 but I get an error in the if statement. Can you resolve the above error?

```
var rem4 = 0;
var rem100 = 0;
var rem400 = 0;

//error Cannot convert call result type "Bool" to expected type "Int"
if (((rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0) | rem400 == 0)){
     daysMonth[2] = 29
}
```

Comment: should probably be `||` instead of `|` in your if-condition!?

Comment: Your () look wrong...  try ((rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0) | (rem400 == 0)) or ((rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0) || (rem400 == 0)) even better...

Comment: @AustinFrench Even better, remove the extra parentheses: `if ((rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0) || rem400 == 0)`.

Comment: Little explanation: `|` is a bitwise or, since the second argument for that or is `rem400` and therefore an `Int` the compiler expects the first one to be an `Int` as well, but gets `(rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0)` which is a `Bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use || (OR operator) for this but you are using | (a single pipe).

```
if (((rem4 == 0 && rem100 != 0) || rem400 == 0)){
     daysMonth[2] = 29
}
```

Comment: Wow didn't even see that. Thank you